# Rotate landscape pages in the pdf view

Tags: xetex, pdf, rotating

I want to rotate the page, when landscape figures/tables has used in the resulting pdf view (generated by xelatex) for more convenient screen reading.

How to get the output in pdf

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{For measuring time, the horizontal gnomon is inserted into the hole above the
scale meant for the current solar month and the staff turned slowly towards the
sun so that the gnomon throws its shadow exactly on the scale below. Where
the end of the shadow touches the numbered scale, the number indicates in
the forenoon the that have elapsed since the sunrise, and in the afternoon, the
number of that are to elapse up to sunset}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With xelatex you can use a special to rotate the page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\special{pdf: put @thispage <</Rotate 90>>}
\caption{For measuring time, the horizontal gnomon is inserted into the hole above the
scale meant for the current solar month and the staff turned slowly towards the
sun so that the gnomon throws its shadow exactly on the scale below. Where
the end of the shadow touches the numbered scale, the number indicates in
the forenoon the that have elapsed since the sunrise, and in the afternoon, the
number of that are to elapse up to sunset}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```